# How to use object variables with a workbook and worksheet? I get "Error 438, Object doesn't support this property or method"

Tags: excel, vba, object, runtime-error

When I run the code below I get

> "Error 438, Object doesn't support this property or method"

at the line: `WBA.WS1.Range("I7").Select`

```
Sub Sandbox()

    Dim WBA As Workbook
    Set WBA = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Reports\Sandbox_data.xlsb")

    Dim WS1 As Worksheet
    Set WS1 = WBA.Sheets("Rpt_Group")

    WBA.WS1.Range("I7").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: There is no need for the `WBA`, as it is already inferred from `WS1`

Comment: That was a perfect answer! Thanks.
How do I mark this as "answered"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for the `WBA`, as it is already inferred from `WS1`